# Is the proof correct?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, algebraic-topology

**Lemma.** Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an algebra of functions on a set $E$ such that $\mathcal{A}$ separates points and vanishes at no point of $E$. Then for any finite number $N$ of points $p_i=(x_i, y_i)$, with all $x_i$ distinct, there exists $f \in \mathcal{A}$ such that the graph of $f$ contains all the $p_{i}$.

**Proof.** We define that
    $$
 f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{h_{n}(x)}{h_{n}(x_{n})}y_{n}\prod_{m\neq n}^{N}\frac{g_{nm}(x)-g_{nm}(x_{m})}{g_{nm}(x_{n})-g_{nm}(x_{m})}
 $$
    where $h_{n}(x), g_{nm}(x)\in\mathcal{A}$ and $g_{nm}=g_{mn}$ for all $m, n\in\{1,2,\dots N\}$ whenever $m\neq n$. It is well-defined because $\mathcal{A}$ separates points and vanishes at no point of $E$. So for every $n$, we can find a function $h_{n}$ such that $h_{n}(x_{n})\neq0$; And we can also find a function $g_{nm}$ such that $g_{nm}(x_{n})\neq g_{nm}(x_{m})$ whenever $x_{n}\neq x_{m}$.
    Then it is easy to check $f(x_{i})=y_{i}$.

---

I don't know if it's off-topic but I really need someone help to check. My instructor didn't agree with the proof but I think it's correct.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is only valid if $\mathcal A$ is a unitary algebra, i.e. contains the constant function $1(x) = 1$. In fact, you assume that the functions $\dfrac{g_{nm}(x) - g_{nm}(x_m)}{g_{nm}(x_n) - g_{nm}(x_m)}$ are in $\mathcal A$ which implies that $g_{nm}(x) - g_{nm}(x_m)$ is in $\mathcal A$. Thus the constant function with value $g_{nm}(x_m)$ must also be $\mathcal A$.

Comment: I understand what you mean. But I had added the function $h\in\mathcal{A}$ as a multiplier to avoid the case that constant functions are not in $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: The question is: Does your proof work for a non-unitary algebra? If so, you should give a correct argument.

Comment: Sorry, but I mean there is no constant function in my formula. Actually, $\frac{g_{n m}(x)-g_{n m}\left(x_{m}\right)}{g_{n m}\left(x_{n}\right)-g_{n m}\left(x_{m}\right)}$ doesn't need to be in $\mathcal{A}$ because it is multiplied by a $h\in\mathcal{A}$. The function $h$ guarantees that for each contant function $g_{nm}(x_{nm})$, the multiplication with $h$ is in $\mathcal{A}$ always, by the definition of an algebra. (If $f\in\mathcal{A}$, then $cf\in\mathcal{A}$ where $c$ is a constant.)

Comment: So I was arguing for the general algebra, not for the unitary algebra only.

Comment: Okay, but then you should completely *rewrite* your answer to avoid the occurence of constant functions. If you can do that, give an answer to your own question. As it is, your answer is at least misleading. By the way, to simplify your formula. you may assume w.l.o.g. that $h_n(x_n) =1$.